# Is there a word that means a day's "antipode" within a year?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, dates

I notice today is September 15th, which is about 6 months after (or before) March the 15th, famously known as the Ides of March (and not much loved by Caesar).

In geography, an *antipode* is the location on the Earth's globe that is directly opposite where you start from. Is there an analogous word for describing "a date that is six months away from a particular date?"

Note: I'm not looking for words like *semi-annual*. I would like to say: "Today is the [*year-antipode*] of the Ides of March."

Comment: I've never heard such a word, it doesn't seem like it would get much use.

Comment: why would anyone use a word like nadir?

Comment: In my experience it's not used much, except metaphorically. Anyway, I think people would just say "It's been 6 months to the day since the Ides of March".

Comment: I just had this idea as a random thought and I'm impressed that someone else thought of it too. Maybe the best you can do is "date antipode"? Or make up your own, like dateipode?:)

Comment: [Half-birthday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-birthday) is probably the nearest thing, meaning the day furthest from your birthday. You could perhaps extend this to half-other things.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. There are many references to perhaps the most well-known such day, June 25, but they don't seem to use any particular terminology to describe this concept. For example:

> Half-Christmas takes place on June 25, **the six month (or halfway point) marker** before Christmas on December 25. (Cady Lang, "[Missing the Festivities?](https://time.com/5613247/what-is-half-christmas-workaholics-holiday/)" Time, 25 June 2019)

> There is also Christmas in June. . . . A Summer Christmas celebration is held on June 25 each year, in Italy and throughout the world. 25 June is **6 months before, or 6 months after (depending how one chooses to look at it)**, the traditional Christmas celebration. ("[Christmas in July](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_in_July)," Wikipedia)

> National Leon Day, celebrated on June 25 every year, marks **the exact halfway point in the year** to Christmas. ("[National Leon Day--June 25, 2023](https://nationaltoday.com/national-leon-day/)," National Today)

(I just realized that today is the Ides of March, so I guess that it's appropriate that this question is finally getting an answer today!)